# Can we use proxy from sencha component without wrapper class (request and response) in its corresponding controller class?

Tags: community, mobile, wrapper-class

I have build an application that has `Sencha` on `VisualForce page`. It has a `proxy` to get `salesforce data`. I have used `Wrapper classes` (Request and Response) in my `controller class` for answering `Sencha proxy`. It is working well. I am getting data correctly.
 But I d'nt know whether an `wrapper class` is necessary or whether we can do it without using an wrapper class. I am just following an `example`.

Can anyone guide me?

Is it necessary to use `wrapper class` for proxy to work because a `response(list of records)` are returned from the controller. I have declared this list of records in response class(wrapper Class).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inner class is not required. Here's a [Sencha Proxy component](https://github.com/financialforcedev/fflib-ext-common/blob/master/src/data/proxy/VFRemote.js) and [sample implementation](https://github.com/financialforcedev/fflib-ext-common-samplecode) that consumes JavaScript Remoting methods without the need for request/response wrappers.

For your CRUD operations (eg on a grid) you could have a controller like this:

```
@RemoteAction static public List<Account> createAccounts(List<Account> accounts) {
    insert accounts;
    return accounts;
}

@RemoteAction static public List<Account> readAccounts(Id parentId) {
    return [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE ParentId = :parentId];
}

@RemoteAction static public List<Account> updateAccounts(List<Account> accounts) {
    update accounts;
    return accounts;
}

@RemoteAction static public void destroyAccounts(List<Account> accounts) {
    delete accounts;
}
```

then configure the component in your project:

```
proxy: {
    type: 'vfremote',
    api: {
        create:  $RemoteAction.AccountsController.createAccounts,
        read:    $RemoteAction.AccountsController.readAccounts,
        update:  $RemoteAction.AccountsController.updateAccounts,
        destroy: $RemoteAction.AccountsController.destroyAccounts,
    }
}
```

The proxy will take care of the rest.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That has helped me a lot. But why did the example had a Wrapper class? Is their any situation that can be solved  only by Wrapper?

Consider that I want to return a 'success' (boolean) and 'errormessage'(string) as a response to the sencha proxy, how can I achieve it. Cause in the above example we can return only "List" of records.